# Pandas groupby + transform taking hours for 600 Million records

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by, ipython

My DataFrame 3 fields are account ,month and salary.

```
account month              Salary
1       201501             10000
2       201506             20000
2       201506             20000
3       201508             30000
3       201508             30000
3       201506             10000
3       201506             10000
3       201506             10000
3       201506             10000
```

I am doing groupby on Account and Month and calculating sum of salary for group. Then removing duplicates.

```
MyDataFrame['salary'] = MyDataFrame.groupby(['account'], ['month'])['salary'].transform(sum)
MyDataFrame = MyDataFrame.drop_duplicates()
```

Expecting output like below:

```
account month              Salary
1       201501             10000
2       201506             40000
3       201508             60000
3       201506             40000
```

It works well for few records. I tried same **for 600 Million records and it is in progress since 4-5 hours**. Initially when I loaded data using pd.read_csv() data acquired 60 GB RAM, till 1-2 hour RAM usages was in between 90 to 120 GB. After 3 hours process is taking 236 GB RAM and it is still running.

Please suggest if any other alternative faster way is available for this.

EDIT:
**Now 15 Minutes** in df.groupby(['account', 'month'], sort=False)['Salary'].sum()

Comment: Shouldn't the statement just be: `df.groupby(['account', 'month']).Salary.sum()`?

Comment: @Alexander I am trying it now, not sure if both are different

Comment: @Alexander I got an error "Incompatible index of inserted columns with frame index" , I run it like MyDataFrame['salary'] = MyDataFrame.groupby(['account'], ['month'])['salary'].sum()

Comment: @Alexander is returns a Series I need dataFrame

Comment: @Alexander I will run it over my 600 million records and provide you update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90380/discussion-between-vipin-and-alexander).

Comment: @Alexander it worked in 15 mins :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to follow up on chrisb's answer and Alexander's comment, you indeed will get more performance out of the `.sum()` and `.agg('sum')` methods.  Here's a Jupyter `%%timeit` output for the three:

[image: Timeit results on groupby methods]

So, the answers that chrisb and Alexander mention are about twice as fast on your very small example dataset.

Also, according to the [Pandas API documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), adding the kwarg `sort=False` will also help performance.  So, your groupby should look something like `df.groupby(['account', 'month'], sort=False)['Salary'].sum()`.  Indeed, when I ran it, it was about 10% faster than the runs shown in the above image.

Comment: all answers were really helpful selecting it because of sort=False

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you're really doing an [aggregation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/groupby.html#aggregation) - `transform` is for when you need the data in the shape as the original frame.  This should be somewhat faster and does it all in one step.

```
df.groupby(['account', 'month'])['Salary'].agg('sum')
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know result

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth downloading the development version of Pandas 0.17.0. They are unlocking the GIL, which controls multi threading. It's going to be natively implemented in the groupby and this blog post suggested speed increases of 3x on a group-mean example.

http://continuum.io/blog/pandas-releasing-the-gil

http://pandas.pydata.org/